# Storing multiple files uploaded in different folders

Tags: php

I'm able to call out all my multiple files in an array and it can be able to be stored in a specific folder for eg. "./documents/".

```
Code for my form:
<form id="Student" name="Student" method="post" action="uploaded.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="upload[]" id="Assign" type="file"/>
<input name="upload[]" id="Testpapers" type="file"/>
<input name="upload[]" id="others" type="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

Code for uploaded.php:
$number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) 
{
 if ($_FILES['upload']['name'][$i] != '') 
{
    $dir = "documents/";
    $number_of_uploaded_files++;
    $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i], $dir. $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i])          

    }
```

Is it possible to store them in different folders respectively? Like store them inside "documents/assign" then "documents/testpapers". I can't think of an idea to detect array index belongs to assign or testpapers, others.

Comment: Reading the comments on the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php) has some great insight on multiple file uploads.  You should check it out.

Comment: Also you might want to consider using ckfinder. I found it to be really good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` won't pass to the server side.

But you could assign the key like below.

```
<input name="upload[assign]" id="Assign" type="file"/>
<input name="upload[testpapers]" id="Testpapers" type="file"/>
<input name="upload[others]" id="others" type="file"/>
```

In server side, you could use `foreach` to loop it.

```
foreach ($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $key => $name) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: @xdazz, in this case, it will pass out the document names only as $name. How can I save it inside different folders ? Like if (upload[assign] = "something") { move_uploaded_files...}

Comment: if ($key == "something") { ... }

Comment: @user976050 You will get key like `assign`, `testpapers`, aren't they you want??

Comment: i tried to echo $key, the value is only 0 and 1. How can i say that if upload[assign] != '', then do this.

Comment: Have you changed the html like I said?

Comment: Ok it submit sorry. But when i merge with my previous code to store inside. The part (move_uploaded_file($upload,
     "documents/".$Student."/Folder/".$upload);), it gives me error.

Comment: if i change to (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],
     "documents/".$Student."/Folder/".$upload);). It gives me error of 'move_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'

Comment: Should be `$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"][$key]`

Comment: Thanks! So from what i understand, i can change the $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]["assign"] also can right?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change field names. Then you can acces noti via $i but through name and decide what to do.